# Solver result has to change more than one cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to run a macro which Solver result has to change more than one cell. Here's the code I've made in Excel 2010:

```
Dim i As Integer Dim j As Integer

For i = 21 To 32 j = 14

SolverOK SetCell:=Cells(i, j), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 16), Cells(i, 29), Cells(i, 54)) SolverSolve SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i

End Sub
```

But I guess I have some syntax error. Could you help me?

Comment: Try sending the `.AddressLocal` property of the `.Cells` object. If you record a macro where two cells are changed, it is fed a string `ByChange:="$A$1,$A$5,$E$5"`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot I've already found the way to change more than one cell. Now I have another problem. Do you know if it's posible to change the target cell of solver when I change the row i?